# Get short JavaScript CustomEvent polyfill to compile in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was under the impression that "all valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript"; but every time I try to use it, I get stuck trying to do something simple :(

In this case, I'm trying to rename some .js files to .ts and get things compiling with as little work as possible. I want to convert to TypeScript progressively; so the focus is on just getting it compiling rather than translating all of the code.

I'm starting with some code that include the CustomEvent polyfill from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

The code is this:

```
(function () {
  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   };

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Then there is some code that calls it:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('typeScriptIsTehCool', { detail: 1 }));
```

However, if you paste all of this into http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground you'll find a few issues:

- `window.Event` is not defined in the base lib
- `document.createEvent` does not return something with an `initCustomEvent` function
- `window.CustomEvent` cannot be set (because `window` is known, and you can't just make up a property on a known type without defining it)
- the call to `new CustomEvent(x, y)` fails because TypeScript uses the lib defintion of `CustomEvent` that does not have this constructor

I've tried various things to get this working; including adding `Event` and `CustomEvent` to `window` in a `.d.ts`, making `CustomEvent` a standard function; and other things, but I just can't eliminate all of the errors.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

Some use of `any` will get you there :

```
interface Window {
    CustomEvent: CustomEvent;
}

(function () {
  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt:CustomEvent = <any>document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   };

  CustomEvent.prototype = Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = <any>CustomEvent;
})();
```

Comment: This has helped me so much! I didn't know that `CustomEvent` is not defined on the `window` object. p/s: The `event` and `params` arguments can be further typed&mdash:this is especially useful if one has `noImplicitAny` enabled :) `function CustomEvent ( event: string, params:CustomEventInit ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You can extend objects by adding new properties/functions on them via the following pattern.

```
interface Window {
    Event : Event;
    CustomEvent(event : any, params : any) : Event;
}
interface Event {
    prototype : Event;
}
declare var CustomEvent: {
    new (event : string, detail : any) : CustomEvent;
}

(function () {
  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = <CustomEvent>document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();

window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('typeScriptIsTehCool', { detail: 1 }));
```

I'm not sure what the param types are so you'll have to add those yourself but this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks; I've added the full code body based on your help on Twitter. Sadly, this doesn't compile in Visual Studio; it doesn't like me redefining CustomEvent :(

`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'CustomEvent' must be of type '{ prototype: CustomEvent; new(): CustomEvent; }', but here has type 'new(event: string, detail: any) => CustomEvent'`

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IWindow extends Window {
    CustomEvent: CustomEvent;
}

interface IParams {
    bubbles: boolean;
    cancelable: boolean;
    detail: any;
}

(() => {
    function CustomEvent(
        event: string,
        params: IParams = {
            bubbles: false,
            cancelable: false,
            detail: undefined
        }
    ) {
        const evt: CustomEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent') as any;
        evt.initCustomEvent(
            event,
            params.bubbles,
            params.cancelable,
            params.detail
        );
        return evt;
    }

    CustomEvent.prototype = Event.prototype;
    const win = window as IWindow;
    win.CustomEvent = CustomEvent as any;
})();
```

IE11 and Typescript yeah its possible to need that combination.